# equivalent to go gocc to generate a shift reduce parser from a bnf grammar file in Java

Tags: java, go, context-free-grammar, parser-generator, bnf

I generated a shift reduce parser using a bnf grammar file using gocc (https://code.google.com/p/gocc/) i would like to generate almost equivalent classes for my parser and lexer in java using the same bnf file.

Any tool you know of that does this and generates a lexer and parser that are close in their structure and algorithms as those generated by gocc ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend asking this on the golang-nuts group. Some (most) of the  core developers are regularly on that list, and this would probably be best answered by them. https://groups.google.com/d/forum/golang-nuts

Comment: thanks a lot, posted it there...